# Disable p-dropdown using just html element reference

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I am using some primeNG components, and I am trying to disable all at the same time. So I did something like this:

```
for(let ele of form.contentViewChild.nativeElement.children){
    ele.disabled = true;
}
```

This works fine with primeNG InputText, InputTextArea and Button. But it does not work with Dropdown, remaining enabled.

If I set "[disabled]=false" directly into the html it works, but I need to do this dynamically using just the element reference in the For above. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that into a Form, you can disable it by the form control assigned.

Anyway you can handle the Dom elements by [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef)